# Read python dict from file

Tags: python, file, dictionary, import

I have a file that contains multiple dictionaries as such this:

```
{'Segment': [{'Price': 271.03, 'Mw': 149.9, '@Number': '1'}, {'Price': 294.46, 'Mw': 106.5, '@Number': '2'}], 'Date': '2014-01-25T23', 'GenName': 60802}
{'Segment': [{'Price': 0, 'Mw': 99, '@Number': '1'}], 'Date': '2014-01-25T00', 'GenName': 57942}
{'Segment': [{'Price': 232.01, 'Mw': 10, '@Number': '1'}, {'Price': 247.31, 'Mw': 15, '@Number': '2'}, {'Price': 251.66, 'Mw': 10, '@Number': '3'}, {'Price': 257.44, 'Mw': 10, '@Number': '4'}, {'Price': 262.07, 'Mw': 9, '@Number': '5'}], 'Date': '2014-01-25T00', 'GenName': 17085}
```

or this:

```
{'Date': '2014-10-21T01', 'Segment': [{'Price': 0, '@Number': '1', 'Mw': 99}], 'GenName': 57942}
{'Date': '2014-10-21T00', 'Segment': [{'Price': 147.1, '@Number': '1', 'Mw': 10}, {'Price': 153.01, '@Number': '2', 'Mw': 15}, {'Price': 158.91, '@Number': '3', 'Mw': 10}, {'Price': 163.64, '@Number': '4', 'Mw': 10}, {'Price': 168.12, '@Number': '5', 'Mw': 9}], 'GenName': 17085}
{'Date': '2014-10-21T20', 'Segment': [{'Price': 209.22, '@Number': '1', 'Mw': 21}], 'GenName': 17541}
```

In other words, the order of each key is not the same within each dictionary.

My questions:
What is the best way to read this dictionaries so that I can call Date, GenName and or Segment regardless of the order?  Is that possible?

Please note... This is not coming from a json file.  If the dictionary is not correctly constructed, I am sure I can modify the script that generates this output.

Comment: If you have control over generating the text files that contain these dictionaries, I'd recommend using shelve or pickle to just serialize the map object onto the disk. Then you can deserialize it and use it as the original map.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parsing values from a JSON file in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835559/parsing-values-from-a-json-file-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have mentioned in comments that you are creating the dictionary by yourself, so storing a dictionary in a pain `.txt` format is not a good idea, Python provides a library known as `Pickle` to preserve any object within, Using [pickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) is very simple.

```
import pickle
#Importing the module

favorite_color = { "Python": "interpreted", "C": "compiled" }
#Initializing a Dictionary (or any Python Object)

pickle.dump( favorite_color, open( "save.p", "wb" ) )
#Saving the Python object in a .p (pickle file)

#Loading the Python object from the Pickle file.
favorite_color = pickle.load( open( "save.p", "rb" ) )
```

You can save any Python object , nested or simple with the help of this module and later access it's value whenever needed.

Comment: Does it have to have the double quotes?

Comment: Double quotes and single quotes are equivalent in python, you can use : `favorite_color = { 'Python': 'interpreted', 'C': 'compiled' }`

Comment: When I run pickle.load I only get one record.  Each file I created with the dump contains multiple records.

Answer (score 2):

Data in your file is python dictionary but not valid json object. As quots are single quot. So you can use `ast.literal_eval()` here. Something like this,

```
with open('mydict.txt', 'r') as js:
    for line in js:
        data = ast.literal_eval(line)
        print data.get('Date')
```

Comment: I have control over the fie that generates these dictionaries.  Are you saying my dictionary is not properly formatted?

Comment: If you have control over that than you must use `Pickle`, should I provide an example ?

Comment: @anmol_uppal  Yes please...  I just read Ambidextrous comment.

Comment: valid json should have double quoted strings. @Alex